# How to get Positions and sizes of matched key points in brute force algorithm

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I want to detect feature points of two consecutive video frames(current and previous frames).For that I used SIFT and brute force algorithm to extract matched key points.Now I want to get only the matched key points into current frame and their positions and sizes. How can I do that ? Is there any specific functions to do that ? Your help is really appreciated

below is my current code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video3.mov')
ret, frame = cap.read()

while(cap.isOpened()):

  prev_frame=frame[:]
  ret, frame = cap.read()

  if ret:

      graycurrent = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      grayprev = cv2.cvtColor(prev_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

      #detect key feature points
      sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

      #kp = sift.detect(graycurrent, None)
      kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(graycurrent, None)

      #draw key points detected
      img1 = cv2.drawKeypoints(graycurrent, kp1,graycurrent, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

      kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(grayprev, None)
      #draw key points detected
      img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(grayprev, kp2,grayprev, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

    # BFMatcher with default params
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(normType=cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck= True)
    matches = bf.match(des1,des2)


    cv2.imshow("grayframe",img1)
    cv2.imshow("prevFrame",img2)

  else:
      print("could not read the frame")

  if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: in the result of matches = bf.match(des1,des2) there should be all the indices of keypoints (and descriptors) you want. Just build new lists of keypoints and descriptors from it.